# How to make icecast as service and restart it?

Tags: bash, audio-streaming, broadcast, icecast, internet-radio

I installed Icecast 2.4.3 on my server using [direct download](https://icecast.org/download/) to get the latest version available.

In this way, I don't use the version distributed by my distribution (debian 8) and thus don't have the daemon activated by default.

I found a script that I modified with my corresponding paths, but the execution is in error.

The script **`icecast.sh`** :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Init file for Icecast server daemon
#
# chkconfig: 345 55 25
# description: Icecast streaming mp3 server daemon
#
# processname: icecast
# config: /etc/icecast.xml
# pidfile: /var/run/icecast.pid

# source function library
# . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions : returns an error on debian 8
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# pull in sysconfig settings
[ -f /etc/sysconfig/icecast ] && . /etc/sysconfig/icecast

RETVAL=0
prog="icecast"

# Some functions to make the below more readable
PREFIX=/usr/local
PATH=$PATH:$PREFIX/bin
PIDFILE=/icecast/icecast.pid
CONF_FILE=/icecast/conf/icecast.xml

[ -f $PREFIX/bin/icecast ] || ( echo Failed to locate icecast binary: $PREFIX/bin/icecast && exit )
[ -f $CONF_FILE          ] || ( echo Failed to locate icecast configuration file: $CONF_FILE && exit )

OPTIONS="-b -c $CONF_FILE"

start()
{
    echo -n $"Starting $prog:"
    ulimit -c unlimited # dump core for debugging purposes
    ulimit -n 32768
    daemon icecast icecast $OPTIONS
    RETVAL=$?
    [ "$RETVAL" = 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/icecast
    echo
    pidof icecast > $PIDFILE
    return $RETVAL
}

stop()
{
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog:"
    killproc icecast -TERM
    RETVAL=$?
    [ "$RETVAL" = 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/icecast
    echo
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return $RETVAL
}

reload()
{
    echo -n $"Reloading $prog:"
    killproc icecast -HUP
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    return $RETVAL
}

condrestart()
{
    [ -e /var/lock/subsys/icecast ] && restart
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        # wait for listening sockets to clear
        echo "Waiting 5 seconds before restarting..."
        sleep 5
        start
        ;;
    reload)
        reload
        ;;
    condrestart)
        condrestart
        ;;
    status)
        status icecast
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|condrestart|status}"
        RETVAL=1
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

And the error I'm getting when I'm doing `sh icecast.sh status` :

```
# sh icecast.sh status
icecast.sh: line 93: status : unknow command
```

**Q1**: How do I fix this error?

**Q2**: How do I get a functional command like `icecast restart service`?

**Q3**: What should I do to restart Icecast automatically if the server restarts itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install a package from you distro (`apt-get install icecast2`, `yum install icecast`, whatever). Usually pakage manager also installs init scripts that will allow you start/stop Icecast.
2. Get your Icecast patht with `which icecast` or `whereis icecast`
3. Download Icecast, build it from source (like if you need to replace official Icecast with Icecast-kh branch or use your own compilation flags).
4. Replace the original icecast binary from (2) with the one that you have build. It's always better to backup the original version, though.
5. `/etc/inid/icecast restart` or `systemctr restart icecast` should work now with your version of Icecast.
6. To make sure your Icecast will start after reboot run 
   `systemctl enable icecast`

Comment: Thank you for your explanations and how to start after reboot

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use the *proper* package from either [debian backports](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/icecast2) or if you e.g. need TLS support the package from [official Xiph.org repositories](https://wiki.xiph.org/Icecast_Server/Installing_latest_version_%28official_Xiph_repositories%29).

This guarantees, that you will receive package updates without having to monitor releases yourself and figure out necessary changes.

Also please note that the latest release for Linux/Unix at this time is ***2.4.2***, as 2.4.3 was a *Windows* only release. The code is identical if compiled for Linux/Unix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's what I said to myself. but as I have the server currently in production... I tried the other way. Do you think I can do a fresh installation in parallel knowing that I won't install it in the same paths? Another thing, is the [Xiph.org repo](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/multimedia:/xiph/Debian_8.0/) version automatically installing the daemon?

Comment: By default and unless overridden, it will install to /usr/local and the binary name will be 'icecast'. While the debian packaging uses the binary name 'icecast2' and non-local prefix. A parallel install should be no problem. Both debian and xiph.org packages install a service. Packages are almost identical anyway. Once you are happy you can run ```make uninstall``` in the icecast source directory to get rid of the bits in /usr/local.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations